# Laravel Valet not resolving sites after install

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

Having a terribly frustrating time not having valet working on a fresh install. Going to any *.test site in my browser just hangs and eventually gets the error message `This site can’t be reached`,  "ping app.test" hangs as well, and *eventually* errors with "ping: cannot resolve app.test: Unknown host". However pinging a different domain (such as ping.xyz errors immediately, as opposed to after ~20 seconds like with *.test).

On Os Sierra, my composer.json looks like the following

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^1.5",
        "laravel/valet": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Since I've seen that `dev-master` resolved this for some people. All my processes seem to be running:

[image: Services running]

However some clues are that `http://localhost/` in my browser returns a page 404 - not found, and running `sudo nginx` returns a bunch of already in user errors:

```
❯ pwd                                                                                                                                                                 
/Users/schorr/.valet

schorr@Andrew-Schorr ~/.valet 
❯ sudo Nginx                                                                                                                                                          
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
```

and `valet fetch-share-url` returns

```
❯ valet fetch-share-url                                                                                                                                                [17:04:53]
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused
...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out, for anyone else in my very specific situation:

I had changed my user name on the same machine, and for whatever reason installing dnsmasq wasn't overwriting the old /Users/user/.valet/dnsmasq.conf file. So at the very bottom I had:

```
conf-file=/Users/OLD_USER_NAME/.valet/dnsmasq.conf

conf-file=/Users/NEW_USER_NAME/.valet/dnsmasq.conf
```

So all I had to do was comment out the OLD_USER_NAME line and was good to go :|

Comment: Where did you make this change? I have the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Append http:// to the url the first time you hit it. For example use http://websitedir.test

I hope it's this simple, let me know.

Try the command 'valet paths' and let me know what that spits out.

Comment: Yep, doesn't even seem to work with `http` appended in front. My Valet links looks like something like: `| test     |     | http://test.test     | /Users/schorr/Sites/test               |`and valet paths returns `["/Users/schorr/Sites"]` :(