# Valet is not able to resolve host after I changed my mac username

Tags: laravel, dnsmasq, laravel-valet

The question title says it all. Things that I tried:

1) Uninstalled laravel/valet composer package globally and reinstalled it. Reinstalled valet. No luck.

2) Deleted the `~/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf` file and ran `valet tld test` to reset all settings. Didn't work.

Output of `brew services list`:

```
dnsmasq   started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mysql@5.7 started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
nginx     started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php       started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
redis     started tanmay /Users/tanmay/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Someone on SO [also had same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750719/laravel-valet-not-resolving-sites-after-install), unfortunately, he did not specify where did he make the changes.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem:

1) Open the following file with a text editor: `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

2) You will find two lines:

```
conf-file=/Users/OLD_USER_NAME/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf

conf-file=/Users/NEW_USER_NAME/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf
```

Comment out the first one